# Dart Language: encoding (related to HttpRequest and http_server package)

Tags: file, encoding, dart, latin1, httpserver

I'm creating a file and writing a String on it with encoding set to LATIN1. However, the finished file is set with a different encoding (us-ascii or utf-8 returned by "file -bi" on Linux, depending on the method I use to get the String).

Here follows the creation method:

```dart
new File("/home/username/dart_test/file.xml").create(recursive: true).then((file) {
    file.writeAsString(_methodReturnsAString(), mode: FileMode.WRITE, encoding: LATIN1);
});
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

**EDIT (RELATED TO ANSWER):**

There's no problem on the method described above. The problem was the data that was being provided to the method inside "writeAsString". That data comes from an HttpRequest that was not being processed properly (in fact, the setting of the encoding to ISO-8859-1 was causing the problem).

Comment: What is the value of `LATIN1`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I think that "LATIN1" stands for the ISO-8859-1 encoding. I tried Encoding.getByName("ISO-8859-1") and it didn't work either.

Comment: I found it. `LATIN1` is from `import 'dart:convert';`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I found the problem. As I'm using http_server to handle HttpBody, I was setting its encoding with ISO-8859-1. When I commented that out (that means leaving HttpBody handling requests with UT8) it did work. I'm going to answer the question with the description of the cause. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with the method described on the question. Actually, the problem lays in an http request body handler that was not set properly.

So I'm answering my own question in order to help others with the same problem.

Here follows my request handler (from http_server package):

```dart
    HttpBodyHandler.processRequest(request/*, defaultEncoding: Encoding.getByName("ISO-8859-1")*/).then((body) {
        // Do something with body.
    }, onError: _printError);
```

Take a look at the commented out "defaultEncoding". That was the cause. I don't think you can set it if you are not processing any files (blobs) on the request. I don't know if there's any situation where you should set it when just processing some String (**I would appreciate if someone could complete this answer with this information**).